# Jquery Not working in for loop but works on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I am creating a thumbnail from videos when the web page is loaded, and i am using jquery to do it..

So I have 3 videos in the html -

```
    <video  width="320" height="240" controls poster="">
  <source src="small.mp4" type="video/mp4">

Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
        <video  width="320" height="240" controls poster="">
  <source src="small.mp4" type="video/mp4">

Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
        <video  width="320" height="240" controls poster="">
  <source src="small.mp4" type="video/mp4">

Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

3 Buttons and 3 image elements -

```
<button onclick="clicker(0)">GET0</button>
<button onclick="clicker(1)">GET1</button>
<button onclick="clicker(2)">GET2</button>

    <img id="img0">
    <img id="img1">
    <img id="img2">
```

Using the clicker function, I can create and add the thumbnail source from each video to each img elements . **It works fine..**

```
function clicker(i) {
  var video = $("video")[i];
  console.info(video);
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = 320;
  canvas.height = 240;
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var dataURI = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
  $('#img'+i).attr("src", dataURI);
}
```

**But when put into a forloop**

```
for (var i = 0;  i < $("video").length; i++) {   

  var video = $("video")[i];
  console.info(video);
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = 640;
  canvas.height = 480;
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var dataURI = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
  $('#img'+i).attr("src", dataURI);

}
```

From what I can gather, the following  `canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');`
is not running in the forloop for some reason

The image sources are just black images, and it doesn't work at all.

I can't see any difference whatsoever?

Comment: Have you put the for loop inside a $(document).ready(function() { ... }); or $(function() { ... }) or otherwise ensure that the for loop is successfully run?

Comment: Yes, tried putting it in them, and it is definately running

Comment: have you tried to put the for loop inside a `$(window).on('load', function() { //for loop here });`? instead that inside a document ready

Comment: Please provide an example in JSBIN live demo.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but why are you using a `for` loop and reselecting all video elements in every iteration instead of just doing `$("video").each()`?

Comment: Can  you show us when  the script is executed? Since a button is waiting for you to click, you might run this loop automatically before the video elements have been loaded fully, which would probably result into this behavior.

Comment: @Glubus How can I show you this? the script is at the end of the file, after the html elements.?

Comment: @GiacomoPaita - I can't upload the videos to jsbin so It throws a cross origin error when trying to create the jsbin.

Comment: @SK2017 if the script tags are at he bottom of the body tag, then it shouldn't be a problem. Still you could verify that it's a timing issue by letting  the loop be executed by another button that is clicked.

Comment: @SK2017 Also if you'd be able to provide a snippet with full code, on jsfiddle for instance, people might be able to debug.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x1e7b21c/

Comment: @SK2017 http://jsbin.com/rehuril/edit?html,output

Comment: @GiacomoPaita I've update it here http://jsbin.com/yujuluzeme/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: you have to wait for your videos have loaded. Assuming they've got an autoplay attribute you can listen to their loadedmetadata event.

Comment: @SK2017 Seems to be a security issue: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that `load` and `ready` aren't sufficient for making sure the videos have loaded before the jquery trys to rip the image from them..

Get the last video loaded on the page and add an event listener to it, when its finished, run the function to rip images from all the videos.

```
$('video')[$('video').length - 1].addEventListener('loadeddata', function() 
        {
            getImages();
        });

  function getImages(){


    $("video").each(function(index, value)
    {
            var video = value;
                console.info(video);
                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                canvas.width = 640;
                canvas.height = 480;
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                var dataURI = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
                $('#img'+index).attr("src", dataURI);
                video.setAttribute('poster', dataURI);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead keep your function as is, (since it is working fine) and call it inside the loop:

```
for (var i = 0;  i < $("video").length; i++) {   
       clicker(i);
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, but a workaround.